# Why I have this weird duplicate error prompt by MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I'm checking this error from the server's error in the company where I current work.

MySQL returns the next message ...
-->

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '439.9618-7403.4014-2014-08-09 10:36:27' for key 'PRIMARY'

But, searching the table, that value doesn't exist. I'll append the result table from mysql, the command and how the table was created. Any help is welcome, thanks.

```
--------+----------+----------+---------------------+----------+------+-----------+------+ <br>
| fixset | gpstime  | gpsutime | servertime          | lat      | hem1 | lon       | hem2 |<br>
+--------+----------+----------+---------------------+----------+------+-----------+------+
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:33:42 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:33:53 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:34:05 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:34:17 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:34:29 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:34:40 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:34:52 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:35:04 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:35:15 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:35:27 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:35:39 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:35:51 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:36:03 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
|    321 | 15:32:01 |        0 | 2014-08-09 10:36:15 | 439.9618 | N    | 7403.4014 | W    |
+--------+----------+----------+---------------------+----------+------+-----------+------+
```

Create Table:

```
create table gps_point (
    fixset int(10) unsigned not null,
    gpstime time,
    gpsutime mediumint(6) unsigned,
    servertime timestamp not null default current_timestamp;
    lat float(8,4),
    hem1 char(2),
    lon float(9,4),
    hem2 char(2),
    primary key (lat, lon, servertime),
    foreign key (fixset) references gps_fixset(fixset)
);
```

I did the same on console, and I got the same error...

```
mysql> INSERT INTO gps_point (fixset,gpstime,gpsutime,servertime,lat,hem1,lon,hem2) VALUES ('000000321','15:32:01','','2014-08-09 10:36:27','0439.9618','N','07403.4012','W');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '439.9618-7403.4014-2014-08-09 10:36:27' for key 'PRIMARY'<br>
```

Comment: seems pretty clear to me. have you tried with a simple select * from where server time = '2014-08-09 10:36:15' ? does it return any result?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Hi @Vland, yes, I did it, but no result is returned :S.

Comment: @MikeMackintosh the version is <"mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2" Any advice is welcome